# What variable is assigned to Stdout in batch?

Tags: batch-file, stdout

I'm trying to get the stdout of the command that was run in batch (not bash). I want to do this ...

```
tasklist /s <server name> | grep -c <Process name>.
```

Output could be `2` for example. I want to use the stdout, 2, for other stuff now.

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pipe again the output of the grep comand ?

Like this : tasklist /s | grep -c | other_task